# Rate or Like...What is the best?

Tags: usability

i want to make a good design for products, services and offers in a mobile application and i need users opinions about this, So i am asking what is the best for usability a "5-Start" rating or a "Like"?

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that YouTube started out with a five star approach, but changed it with a "like" system later. The reason for this was that most ratings given were either a 1 or a 5.

Do you expect many nuanced ratings?

Also see: http://youtube-global.blogspot.nl/2009/09/five-stars-dominate-ratings.html

Comment: It was like that. And it was because there was a lot of ambiguity behind what a 3 star really meant. Does that mean I like it enough or is it a trailing "not so good" review.

Comment: When you recommend something, you don't say "I give it a 4 star," when talking to other people. You either recommend it or you don't and you say you either like it or you don't. It was shown that the reaction to these things were so binary as apposed to so open and "5 faceted"